# adb shell input text Android 11 inCall

Tags: android, android-11, dtmf, adb

I have a problem when sending DTMF events inside of an active call.

I am using `adb shell input text #0123*` to send DTMF tones. This was working good so far for older Android versions. Starting from Android 11 (I didn't check 12 yet), special characters * and # are not working anymore and sending 8 and 3 instead.

If I am sending the text at other text fields, the special chars are formatted correctly, the error is only occurring inside the call application when having an active call and trying to send DTMF tones via dialpad.

**Edit:**
I tried sending with ' escaped:

```
User:~$ adb -s RF8N31NZ5SK shell
x1s:/ $ input text '#*'
x1s:/ $
```

But result is the same:

[image]

**Edit-2:**
It looks like dialer is not allowing special chars anymore on Android >= 11. I managed to do it via keyevents KEYCODE_POUND and KEYCODE_STAR:

```
User:~$ adb -s RF8N31NZ5SK shell
x1s:/ $ input keyevent KEYCODE_POUND
x1s:/ $ input keyevent KEYCODE_STAR
x1s:/ $
```

Comment: Is tapping on the button's coordinates an option for you?

Comment: No, unfortunately I want to deal with different screens and Android versions, so coordinates will be changing. I managed to use KEYCODE_POUND and KEYCODE_STAR to send it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding apostrophe to surround text to sent because # character is used for comments on Android shell :

```
adb shell input text '#1234*'
```

It worked on my side with Android 11

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working, i have sent "input text '#*'", but it is sending 38

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the hash character and place the whole input text in double quotes:

```
adb shell input text "\#1234*"
```

Note: In my tests I had to use double quotes, single quotes were not working, with single quotes the typed text was `\#1234*`. But this may depend on the used terminal/platform for executing the whole command (in my case Windows 10 command-line/cmd.exe).

This commands works for me and

Comment: This is still not working. Did you test this exactly during an active call with dialpad opened? If I am trying in another field, like messages, it is also typing # and *. Only in an active call when sending DTMF, it is replacing with 3 and 8 ...

Comment: @Helmutchecker I tested if the command works and the text is entered correctly in an Android app. If it does not work for you test it in a different app. If it does work there then the dialer is simply not accepting `#` as input text. You should also consider to add delays to increase the chance that the DTMF tone is correctly recognized by the audio server you are connected to.

Comment: As I said, input in another app, like messages, is working fine without problems. I guess you are right and it is a problem with the dialer (must have been changes in Android 11, as it was working well in older versions). Do you have an idea how to solve this, or what can I do about this?

Comment: The dialer UI should be part of the dialer app which can be replaced in Android. May be a different dialer app works in your case or even provides a more suitable interface for whatever you want to to with the DTMF tones.